# C++ operator << calling ::ostream instead of std::ostream

Tags: c++, io, stl

I have searched high and low, but have not found an answer, so please excuse if this is a duplicate.

I have some very old C++ code that I am trying to lightly convert into this millennium.  The code still compiles in Visual Studio 6 and needs to continue doing so, but I am also trying to get it working in Visual Studio 2017.  I have done this before, but with many changes to the header files etc., this time I am trying a more measured approach.

The code already uses a mix of stl and non-stl, old and new io headers etc., so it's a mess waiting to explode.

As a simple start, I just replaced iostream.h with iostream to see what would happen.  I got some compiler errors where the code had ::ostream in it, so changing that to std::ostream fixed that issue.  Next I get an issue with an overloaded << operator, all of the bits in there are using std::iostream, but it seems that the << commands are trying to use ostream instead (or basic_ostream).

What am I missing?  I assume I have to change out some more header files that are importing the old io classes.

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PrinterInfo& pi)
{
    os << pi.Idx() << ": " << pi.Name() << ", "
            << PrinterInfo::MapPrinterType(pi.GetPrinterType()) << ", "
            << PrinterInfo::MapPaperType(pi.GetPaperType()) << ", "
            << PrinterInfo::MapPrintFormat(pi.GetPrintFormat()) << ", "
            << PrinterInfo::MapRasType(pi.GetRasType()) << ", "
            << PrinterInfo::MapNPS(pi.NPS()) << ", "
            << "dpx = " << pi.Duplex() << ", "
            << "tray = " << pi.Tray2() << ", "
            << "port = " << pi.PortNo();

    return os;
}
```

The PrinterInfo class has an override for the << operator as well:

```
    inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const PrinterOption& po)
{
    os << "(" << po.Installed() << ", " << po.Enabled() << ")";
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Is `PrinterOption` or `PrinterInfo` in a separate namespace?

Comment: Yes, most of this code was written in the 90's, so in the general namespace, nothing specified.

Comment: So, what is the problem with this code? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ? Do you get compiler errors, unexpected output, something else?

Comment: Well, it appears to me that the << statements in the function are calling the ostream operator, instead of that of the std::ostream class.  So the code then complains that it cannot for instance find an operator for the << pi.Duplex bit because the operator for that is using std::ostream.  So either I have to use some other syntax with the << to get it to use ostream or figure out why it's using the old ostream in the first place.

Comment: Show the complete text of the error message, as well as the declaration of `PrinterInfo::Duplex()` and the declaration of `operator<<` that's supposed to be able to print whatever it returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if that is the case but if you implement the body of a function INSIDE the class header file remove the inline keyword, i had a similar problem and i waste 2-3 whole days and a lot of recoding to realise this...

Comment: I will give that a try.

Comment: Go figure.  Moved those two operators to the cpp file and it worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, this is an include error because the inline is actually copying the body of the function where the call happens to avoid the overhead of calling a small function many times. So the linker logically complains about multiple includes of the header file that is already used somewhere else.